# file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1, Failed to enable crypto

Tags: php, rest, ssl, file-get-contents

I’ve been trying to access this particular REST service from a PHP page I’ve created on our server.  I narrowed the problem down to these two lines.  So my PHP page looks like this:

```
<?php
$response = file_get_contents("https://maps.co.weber.ut.us/arcgis/rest/services/SDE_composite_locator/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Street=&SingleLine=3042+N+1050+W&outFields=*&outSR=102100&searchExtent=&f=json");

echo $response; ?>
```

The page dies on line 2 with the following errors:

> - Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>     OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>     routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in
>     ...php on line 2
>
>   - Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in ...php on
>       line 2
>   - Warning:
>       file_get_contents(`https://maps.co.weber.ut.us/arcgis/rest/services/SDE_composite_locator/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Street=&SingleLine=3042+N+1050+W&outFields=*&outSR=102100&searchExtent=&f=json`):
>       failed to open stream: operation failed in ...php on line 2

We’re using a Gentoo server.  We recently upgraded to PHP version 5.6.  It was after the upgrade when this problem appeared.

I found when I replace the REST service with an address like `https://www.google.com`; my page works just fine.

In an earlier attempt I set `“verify_peer”=>false`, and passed that in as an argument to file_get_contents, as described here:  [file_get_contents ignoring verify_peer=>false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15076819/file-get-contents-ignoring-verify-peer-false)  But like the writer noted; it made no difference.

I’ve asked one of our server administrators if these lines in our php.ini file exist:

- extension=php_openssl.dll
- allow_url_fopen = On

He told me that since we’re on Gentoo, openssl is compiled when we build; and it’s not set in the php.ini file.

I also confirmed that `allow_url_fopen` is working.  Due to the specialized nature of this problem; I’m not finding a lot of information for help.  Have any of you come across something like this?  Thanks.

Comment: If you use Kaspersky, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54791481/3549317

Comment: I found that I only get this error when scraping from within the same web site (not locally), ie: scraping a different website to where the script is run worked perfectly.

Comment: For those of you getting this in 2021, please see this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69413223/letsencrypt-certificate-invalid-expired-when-seemingly-not-in-phpmailer-tls-op/69413224#69413224

Answer (score 493, accepted):

This was an enormously helpful link to find:

http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php

An official document describing the changes made to open ssl in PHP 5.6
From here I learned of one more parameter I should have set to false:  "verify_peer_name"=>false

> **Note:** This has *very* significant security implications. Disabling verification potentially permits a [MITM attacker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) to use an invalid certificate to eavesdrop on the requests. While it may be useful to do this in local development, other approaches should be used in production.

So my working code looks like this:

```
<?php
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  

$response = file_get_contents("https://maps.co.weber.ut.us/arcgis/rest/services/SDE_composite_locator/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Street=&SingleLine=3042+N+1050+W&outFields=*&outSR=102100&searchExtent=&f=json", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

echo $response; ?>
```

Comment: this breaks SSL certification and is a security hole

Comment: I'm trying send a request to the discord API (http://discordapp.com/api/webhooks..." ) but still getting the error.

Comment: @hypery2k but specifically in cases where an external request is being made, right? I have to read a json file on the site's server & this method works. Not sure if SSL Certification should be necessary in that type of circumstance...

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I get the following error:
`Warning: file_get_contents({my_url}): Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`

Answer (score 184):

You shouldn't just turn off verification. Rather you should download a certificate bundle, perhaps the [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) bundle will do?

Then you just need to put it on your web server, giving the user that runs php permission to read the file.  Then this code should work for you:

```php
$arrContextOptions= [
    'ssl' => [
        'cafile' => '/path/to/bundle/cacert.pem',
        'verify_peer'=> true,
        'verify_peer_name'=> true,
    ],
];

$response = file_get_contents(
    'https://maps.co.weber.ut.us/arcgis/rest/services/SDE_composite_locator/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Street=&SingleLine=3042+N+1050+W&outFields=*&outSR=102100&searchExtent=&f=json',
    false,
    stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)
);
```

Hopefully, the root certificate of the site you are trying to access is in the curl bundle.  If it isn't, this still won't work until you get the root certificate of the site and put it into your certificate file.

Comment: theres also a helpful function `stream_context_set_default` which can be used so you dont have to pass it into file_get_contents everytime

Comment: If you are having issues getting this to work, you could try adding `"capture_peer_cert_chain" => true` to `$arrContextOptions`.  Then the call to file_get_contents will also include the certificate chain of the host that you are trying to connect to (base64 encoded).  I believe the last certificate listed in the output is the root certificate and that certificate must be in the cert file you are using, in order for this to work.  Note that, there may be some other issue with the host or client side that's causing it to fail (i.e. expired host cert, client time is incorrect, etc)

Comment: I found this extremely helpful. Better answer than the accepted. Our server has a cert from RapidSSL where its not present for php on any machine we try to connect to the server with. So we have to squirrel the rapidssl2017.pem away and let php know (thanks to this answer). So being able to tell file_get_contents() where to look for it... is much nicer than using curl for a grab.

Comment: Sadly, after I got everything working in my prior comment on oct 10th... today I come back from vacation, and its all stopped working. No amount of linking or grabbing a pem file is working. Had to temporarily resort to disabling verify :( Will be posting a brand new question sometime here about our specific issue with these crappy RapidSSL certs.

Comment: How could set permissions for the `pem` file?

Comment: Out of everything that I have tried for over 2 days, after updating to http24 and php7, this is the only solution which worked. However I am not sure about the security concerns. I created a new key using openssl and used that instead of the link provided for file_get_contents. I am not sure why things stopped working earlier and why it is working now. I only hope that there are no security holes. At least it is working now.

Comment: In case anyone needs additional information on `file_get_contents` SSL context. http://php.net/manual/en/context.ssl.php

Comment: It works but I wnat to know: Does this "cacert.pem" file downloaded from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem ever expire? Do I need to download another copy in a few months time or will it work indefinitely?

Comment: Well, I've checked the expiration of the "cacert.pem" file with the "openssl" command line and it says it expires on 2028. I used this: openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in cacert.pem

Comment: From a security perspective: next to the usage of the cafile stream context option, it could be very important to also define the allowed ciphers in the ciphers stream context option and forbid those SSL versions which are known as vulnerable. Also  setting the stream context option disable_compression to true is recommended to mitigate the CRIME attack vector.

Comment: i am getting the same exception but with `exif_imagetype` which has only 1 parameter , i am on local host with self signed certificate for my virtual host using xampp, any ideas ?

Comment: This solution fixed my issue with my Amazon Web Services Lightsail server running PHP on IIS. My file_get_contents command used in a JSON call had been working but suddenly stopped working. This solution corrected the problem. AWS Support could not resolve the problem. My application is now working perfectly again. Thank You!

Answer (score 45):

I fixed this by making sure that that OpenSSL was installed on my machine and then adding this to my php.ini:

```
openssl.cafile=/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
```

Comment: I used the same method using PHP 7 on IIS, downloaded the `cert.pem` file and set the `php.ini` like this, and it worked: `openssl.cafile=D:\Tools\GnuWin32\bin\cacert.pem`

Comment: I downloaded the PEM file from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html - fixed the problem for me on Windows with a particular gstatic.com URL.

Comment: Downloading the PEM file from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html didn't work for me on Centos 7. I created a bundle certificate by concatenating main certificate and pkcs7 and place it on server and then specify openssl.cafile path. +1 for right answer and direction.

Comment: When creating a bundle don't forget to convert pkcs to pem file before concating it to main certification

Answer (score 35):

You can get around this problem by writing a custom function that uses curl, as in:

```
function file_get_contents_curl( $url ) {

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );

  $data = curl_exec( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );

  return $data;

}
```

Then just use `file_get_contents_curl` instead of `file_get_contents` whenever you're calling a url that begins with https.

Comment: Top solution just disabled SSL which is unsafe - this works a lot better.

Comment: This is a simple solution, even though it is not as direct as the one by elitechief. The accepted one leads to a security breach.

Comment: Leads to similar error on my side: `User Notice: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

Comment: How is this functionally different than file_get_contents? It does nothing to address the SSL issue.

Comment: @MarshallC My answer is not functionally different than file_get_contents. It just solves the problem under most circumstances without creating a security nightmare.

Answer (score 20):

Working for me, I am using PHP 5.6. openssl extension should be enabled and while calling google map api verify_peer make false
Below code is working for me.

```
<?php
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
         "verify_peer"=>false,
         "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);  
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="
      . $latitude
      . ","
      . $longitude
      . "&sensor=false&key="
      . Yii::$app->params['GOOGLE_API_KEY'];

$data = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

echo $data;
?>
```

Answer (score 14):

After falling victim to this problem on centOS after updating php to php5.6 I found a solution that worked for me.

Get the correct directory for your certs to be placed by default with this

```
php -r "print_r(openssl_get_cert_locations()['default_cert_file']);"
```

Then use this to get the cert and put it in the default location found from the code above

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -O <default location>
```

Comment: Thankyou the only thing that worked for me and stiaghtforward

Answer (score 11):

At first you need to have enabled `curl` extension in PHP. Then you can use this function:

```
function file_get_contents_ssl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3000); // 3 sec.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000); // 10 sec.
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

It works similar to function [file_get_contents(..)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Example:

```
echo file_get_contents_ssl("https://www.example.com/");
```

Output:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>
...
```

Comment: This solution is not secure, due to the use of `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false`.

Comment: @BadHorsie Yes, but it works.

Comment: Sure, but that's like if the lock on the door to your house was broken you fixed it by just removing the entire lock.

Answer (score 9):

You basically have to set the environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE to the path of the PEM file of the ssl-certificate downloaded from the following link : http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.

It took me a lot of time to figure this out.

Answer (score 9):

following below steps will fix this issue,

1. Download the CA Certificate from this link: https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
2. Find and open php.ini
3. Look for `curl.cainfo` and paste the **absolute path** where you have download the Certificate. `curl.cainfo ="C:\wamp\htdocs\cert\cacert.pem"`
4. Restart WAMP/XAMPP (apache server).
5. It works!

hope that helps !!

Comment: is this safe? i love easy solutions but im missing some information here..

Comment: for testing is ok

Comment: Setting `curl.cainfo` didn't work for me, but setting `openssl.cafile=C:\xampp\certs\cacert.pem` worked.

Answer (score 8):

If your PHP version is 5, try installing cURL by typing the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with `cURL`.

Comment: Installing the php curl should be the correct answer! For my Mac system, I'm using port, and the command is: `sudo port install php70-curl`

Answer (score 8):

```php
<?php
    $stream_context = stream_context_create([
        "ssl" => [
            "verify_peer" => false,
            "verify_peer_name" => false
        ]
    ]);  
    
    $response = file_get_contents("https://maps.co.weber.ut.us/arcgis/rest/services/SDE_composite_locator/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?Street=&SingleLine=3042+N+1050+W&outFields=*&outSR=102100&searchExtent=&f=json", false, $stream_context);
    
    echo $response;
?>
```

Just tested of PHP 7.2, it's working well.

**EDIT:** Also tested and working on PHP 7.1

Comment: Tested on PHP 8.x, worked well!

Answer (score 6):

Had the same error with PHP 7 on XAMPP and OSX.

The above mentioned answer in [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151993/2360229) is good, but it did not completely solve the problem for me. I had to provide the complete certificate chain to make file_get_contents() work again. That's how I did it:

**Get root / intermediate certificate**

First of all I had to figure out what's the root *and* the intermediate certificate.

The most convenient way is maybe an online cert-tool like the [ssl-shopper](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=www.whatsyoururl.de)

There I found three certificates, one server-certificate and two chain-certificates (one is the root, the other one apparantly the intermediate).

All I need to do is just search the internet for both of them. In my case, this is the root:

**thawte DV SSL SHA256 CA**

And it leads to his url [thawte.com](https://www.thawte.com/roots/thawte_Primary_Root_CA-G3_SHA256.pem). So I just put this cert into a textfile and did the same for the intermediate. Done.

**Get the host certificate**

Next thing I had to to is to download my server cert. On Linux or OS X it can be done with openssl:

```bash
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect whatsyoururl.de:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform PEM > /tmp/whatsyoururl.de.cert
```

**Now bring them all together**

Now just merge all of them into one file. (Maybe it's good to just put them into one folder, I just merged them into one file). You can do it like this:

```bash
cat /tmp/thawteRoot.crt > /tmp/chain.crt
cat /tmp/thawteIntermediate.crt >> /tmp/chain.crt
cat /tmp/tmp/whatsyoururl.de.cert >> /tmp/chain.crt
```

**tell PHP where to find the chain**

There is this handy function openssl_get_cert_locations() that'll tell you, where PHP is looking for cert files. And there is this parameter, that will tell file_get_contents() where to look for cert files. Maybe both ways will work. I preferred the parameter way. (Compared to the solution mentioned above).

So this is now my PHP-Code

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "cafile" => "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/share/openssl/certs/chain.pem",
        "verify_peer"=> true,
        "verify_peer_name"=> true,
    ),
);

$response = file_get_contents($myHttpsURL, 0, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

That's all. file_get_contents() is working again. Without CURL and hopefully without security flaws.

Comment: What's the file `chain.pem`? Is this `chain.crt`?

Comment: It is not the chain.crt, that's for the actual certificate. It's the list if intermediate certificates, aka certificate chain. You don't necessarily need it. Use a SSL cert checker to find out if you need it. If so, you may search for the name of your cert issuer + the term "chain" or "intermediate" to find the correct file.

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add to this since I ran into the same problem and nothing I could find anywhere would work (e.g downloading the cacert.pem file, setting cafile in php.ini etc.)

If you are using NGINX and your SSL certificate comes with an "intermediate certificate", you need to combine the intermediate cert file with your main "mydomain.com.crt" file and it should work. Apache has a setting specific for intermediate certs, but NGINX does not so it must be within same file as your regular cert.

Answer (score 5):

Reason for this error is that PHP does not have a list of trusted certificate authorities.

PHP 5.6 and later try to load the CAs trusted by the system automatically. Issues with that can be fixed. See http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php for more information.

PHP 5.5 and earlier are *really* hard to setup correctly since you manually have to specify the CA bundle in each request context, a thing you do not want to sprinkle around your code.
So I decided for my code that for PHP versions < 5.6, SSL verification simply gets disabled:

```
$req = new HTTP_Request2($url);
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.6.0', '<')) {
    //correct ssl validation on php 5.5 is a pain, so disable
    $req->setConfig('ssl_verify_host', false);
    $req->setConfig('ssl_verify_peer', false);
}
```

Comment: This helped me find my problem. Even though I'm on PHP 5.6 I was using an outdated api client library that manually specified an old CA file using the cafile context option as per your link above. Removing that from the api client library fixed it for me. Presumably PHP started using OpenSSLs trusted bundle

Answer (score 3):

Had the same ssl-problem on my developer machine (php 7, xampp on windows) with a self signed certificate trying to fopen a "https://localhost/..."-file. Obviously the root-certificate-assembly (cacert.pem) didn't work.
I just copied manually the code from the apache server.crt-File in the downloaded cacert.pem and did the openssl.cafile=path/to/cacert.pem entry in php.ini

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to try is to re-install `ca-certificates` as detailed [here](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002459314-Error-while-sending-an-email-via-contact-form-with-recaptcha-used).

```
# yum reinstall ca-certificates
...
# update-ca-trust force-enable 
# update-ca-trust extract
```

And another thing to try is to explicitly allow the one site's certificate in question as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38272278) (especially if the one site is your own server and you already have the .pem in reach).

```
# cp /your/site.pem /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
# update-ca-trust extract
```

I was running into this exact SO error after upgrading to PHP 5.6 on CentOS 6 trying to access the server itself which has a cheapsslsecurity certificate which maybe it needed to be updated, but instead I installed a letsencrypt certificate and with these two steps above it did the trick. I don't know why the second step was necessary.

---

Useful Commands

View openssl version:

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

View PHP cli ssl current settings:

```
# php -i | grep ssl
openssl
Openssl default config => /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf
openssl.cafile => no value => no value
openssl.capath => no value => no value
```

Answer (score 2):

### Fix for macos 12.4 / Mamp 6.6 /  Homebrew 3.5.2 / Openssl@3

##### Terminal

Check version

```
openssl version -a
```

Mine was pointing to:

```
...
OPENSSLDIR: "/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@3"
...
```

So I looked through homebrew's dir `/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@3` and found the cert.pem and made sure my Mamp's current version of php's php.ini file was pointing to homebrew's correct openssl version's cert.pem

##### add to php.ini

```ini
openssl.cafile=/opt/homebrew/etc/openssl@3/cert.pem
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding errors similar to

> [11-May-2017 19:19:13 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Have you checked the permissions of the cert and directories referenced by openssl?

You can do this

```
var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());
```

To get something similar to this

```
array(8) {
  ["default_cert_file"]=>
  string(21) "/usr/lib/ssl/cert.pem"
  ["default_cert_file_env"]=>
  string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE"
  ["default_cert_dir"]=>
  string(18) "/usr/lib/ssl/certs"
  ["default_cert_dir_env"]=>
  string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR"
  ["default_private_dir"]=>
  string(20) "/usr/lib/ssl/private"
  ["default_default_cert_area"]=>
  string(12) "/usr/lib/ssl"
  ["ini_cafile"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ini_capath"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

This issue frustrated me for a while, until I realized that my "certs" folder had 700 permissions, when it should have had 755 permissions. Remember, this is not the folder for keys but certificates. I recommend reading this [this link on ssl permissions.](https://serverfault.com/questions/259302/best-location-for-ssl-certificate-and-private-keys-on-ubuntu)

Once I did

```
chmod 755 certs
```

The problem was fixed, at least for me anyway.

Comment: Yay! CHMOD was my issue as well ;-) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for another secure page when using `wget` or `file_get_contents`.  A lot of research (including some of the responses on this question) resulted in a simple solution - installing Curl and PHP-Curl - If I've understood correctly, Curl has the Root CA for Comodo which resolved the issue

Install Curl and PHP-Curl addon, then restart Apache

```
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install php-curl
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

All now working.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was running XAMPP on a Windows 10 machine (localhost) and recently upgraded to PHP 8.  I was trying to open a localhost HTTPS link via file_get_contents().

In my php.ini file, there was a line that read:

```ini
openssl.cafile="C:\Users\[USER]\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt"
```

This was the certificate bundle being used to validate "outside" URLs, and was a package from Mozilla as some people have discussed. I don't know if XAMPP came that way or if I set it up in the past.

At some point I had set up HTTPS on my localhost, resulting in another certificate bundle. This bundle needed to be used to validate "localhost" URLs.  To remind myself where that bundle was, I opened httpd-ssl.conf and found the line that read:

```
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
```

(The complete path was C:\Users[USER]\xampp\apache\conf\ssl.crt\server.crt)

To make both localhost and outside URLs work simultaneously, I copied the contents of my localhost "server.crt" file into Mozilla's bundle "curl-ca-bundle.crt".

```
.
.
.
m7I1HrrW9zzRHM76JTymGoEVW/MSD2zuZYrJh6j5B+BimoxcSg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Localhost--I manually added this
================================
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDGDCCAgCgAwIBAgIQIH+mTLNOSKlD8KMZwr5P3TANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAU
...
```

At that point I could use file_get_contents() with both localhost URLs and outside URLs with no additional configuration.

```
file_get_contents("https://localhost/...");
file_get_contents("https://google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$csm = stream_context_create(['ssl' => ['capture_session_meta' => TRUE]]);
$sourceCountry = file_get_contents("https://api.wipmania.com/{$ip}?website.com", FALSE, $csm);
echo $sourceCountry;
```

Comment: [Please do not post an answer that consists essentially of
code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.