# SSL operation failed with code 1 "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser"

Tags: php

I'm trying to scrape a https page with the following snippet using the "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" library:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://domain.com/');
```

But it's throwing an error

```
SSL operation failed with code 1
```

I want to nuke verification as per [file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. And more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more) , the solution was to add this:

```
    $arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
    "verify_peer"=>false,
    "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);
```

But I'm not sure what to change within the library's function:

```
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
```

or is it something I should be adding here?:

```
$dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);

$contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
```

Sorry I know it's probably a simple solution but I've been scratching my head for the past 3 hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you paste the following right after the open curly brace for the file_get_html function, it will work:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'follow_location' => false
        ),
        'ssl' => array(
            "verify_peer"=>false,
            "verify_peer_name"=>false,
        ),
    )
);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering Erik.  It's generally best if you can put all the relevant code into your answer, rather than link to an image of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works for me:
    `$context=stream_context_create(array('ssl'=>array('verify_peer'=>false,'verify_peer_name'=>false)));`

Comment: Just as a late notice: The part with the follow_location can cause your code to fail since you may receive a 3** code with a status page. So if you run into blank pages, you may set this to true or don't include it all since true should be default.

Comment: worked perfectly, thank you very much for your time! [+1]