# Saving User's Profile Picture from facebook API - PHP SDK V.5

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0, save-image

**Scenario:** I am working on an app through which i need to download the user's profile picture from Facebook, apply a specific filter and then re-upload and set it as profile picture, which is possible using this trick. '**makeprofile=1**'

```
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?pid=xyz&id=abc&makeprofile=1
```

---

**Problem:**
So the problem i am facing is while downloading the picture from the received URL via API. I am obtaining the picture URL this way:

```
$request = $this->fb->get('/me/picture?redirect=false&width=9999',$accessToken); // 9999 width for the desired size image

// return object as in array form
$pic = $request->getGraphObject()->asArray();

// Get the exact url
$pic = $pic['url'];
```

---

Now i want to save the image from obtained URL to a directory on my server, so that i can apply the filter and re-upload it.
When i use **file_get_contents($pic)** it throws following error

```
file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

I have tried a few other methods as well but could not get this fixed. Any help would be appreciated :)

**NOTE:** I am doing this through Codeigniter and on localhost for now.

Comment: Can you upload the picture successfully back to Facebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found the solution myself and decided to answer so that if that can help someone else facing the same problem.

We need to pass a few parameters to the **file_get_contents()** function

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
                "ssl"=>array(
                    "verify_peer"=>false,
                    "verify_peer_name"=>false,
                ),
);
$profile_picture = @file_get_contents($profile_picture, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
// Use @ to silent the error if user doesn't have any profile picture uploaded
```

Now the **$profile_picture** has the picture, we can save it anywhere in the following way.

```
$path = 'path/to/img';  //E.g assets/images/mypic.jpg

file_put_contents($path, $profile_picture);
```

That's all :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a potential duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more).

I'm just gonna repeat [elitechief21's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28701786/2272637) here: you should NOT disable SSL certificate because that creates a security hole in your application.

But rather, you should download a list of trusted certificate authorities (CA) (e.g. [curl.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html)) and use it together with your file_get_contents, like this:

```
$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "cafile" => "/path/to/bundle/cacert.pem",
        "verify_peer"=> true,
        "verify_peer_name"=> true,
    ),
);
$profile_picture = @file_get_contents($picture_url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `file_get_connects()`

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/'.$profileId.'/picture?type=large&redirect=false');
$picture = json_decode($json, true);
$img = $picture['data']['url'];
```

> where **$profileId** variable contain user profile id and 
>   **type** paramete can be square , large , small, normal according to your requirement which size you want

Now `$img` variable contain your image data. Save image file on server using `file_put_contents()`

```
$imagePath = 'path/imgfolder';  //E.g assets/images/mypic.jpg
file_put_contents($imagePath, $img);
```

Comment: Pankaj, i was having errors when using file_put_contents() functions so the parameters mentioned in my answer worked for me. Thank you for your answer as well :-)