# get_headers(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: php

Hey i try to get header information of url ,

when i use the protocol http it's work fine , but when i use https it's not working

the url : https://200.35.78.130/

```
Warning: get_headers(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in
Warning: get_headers(): Failed to enable crypto in 
Warning: get_headers(https://200.35.78.130/): failed to open stream: operation failed in /
```

this is my code

```
print_r(get_headers("https://200.35.78.130/", 1));
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That error occurs when you're trying to access a URL without a valid SSL certificate. You can work around this by [overriding the default stream context](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php), which will affect all subsequent file operations (including remote URLs)

```
<?php
stream_context_set_default( [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
]);

print_r(get_headers('https://200.35.78.130/'));
```

Alternatively, if you're using PHP 7.1+, you can create a temporary context using `stream_context_create` and pass it directly to the function, to avoid overriding the default:

```
$context = stream_context_create( [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ],
]);

print_r(get_headers('https://200.35.78.130/', 0, $context));
```

Thanks to Matthijs Wessels in the comments for pointing it out.

Comment: damn, 5 minutes to get the answer you needed - that's impressive.

Comment: get_headers in php7 now also optionally take a context as a parameter. You can create a context using [stream_context_create](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php).

Comment: For anyone looking to use self-signed SSL certificates WITHOUT disabling SSL verification, [check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28701786/1717535) instead.

Answer (score -2):

Because you installed the SSL certificate without an intermediate key