# Laravel : file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1

Tags: laravel, macos, laravel-5

> file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error
>   messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Getting this error in local server. Working fine in Production

OS: macOS Mojave

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1 (certificate verify failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922504/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-certificate-verify-failed)

Comment: Thank you forpointing out let me check