# Google reCAPTCHA error while sending mails

Tags: php, recaptcha

first of all thanks in advance for any help.
I uploaded a test page so you can  see the problem: http://senoranabogados.com.ar/test1.html

And this is the php code i'm using:

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$toemails = array();

$toemails[] = array(
                'email' => 'Your email', // Your Email Address
                'name' => 'Your Name' // Your Name
            );

// Form Processing Messages
$message_success = 'We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your Message and will get Back to you as soon as possible.';

// Add this only if you use reCaptcha with your Contact Forms
$recaptcha_secret = 'your-recaptcha-secret-key'; // Your reCaptcha Secret

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// If you intend you use SMTP, add your SMTP Code after this Line


if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
    if( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] != '' ) {

        $name = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-name'] : '';
        $email = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-email'] : '';
        $phone = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] : '';
        $service = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-service'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-service'] : '';
        $subject = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] : '';
        $message = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-message'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-message'] : '';

        $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message From Contact Form';

        $botcheck = $_POST['template-contactform-botcheck'];

        if( $botcheck == '' ) {

            $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
            $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
            foreach( $toemails as $toemail ) {
                $mail->AddAddress( $toemail['email'] , $toemail['name'] );
            }
            $mail->Subject = $subject;

            $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
            $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
            $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
            $service = isset($service) ? "Service: $service<br><br>" : '';
            $message = isset($message) ? "Message: $message<br><br>" : '';

            $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

            $body = "$name $email $phone $service $message $referrer";

            // Runs only when File Field is present in the Contact Form
            if ( isset( $_FILES['template-contactform-file'] ) && $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
                $mail->IsHTML(true);
                $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['name'] );
            }

            // Runs only when reCaptcha is present in the Contact Form
            if( isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
                $recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
                $response = file_get_contents( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $recaptcha_secret . "&response=" . $recaptcha_response );

                $g_response = json_decode( $response );

                if ( $g_response->success !== true ) {
                    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Captcha not Validated! Please Try Again." }';
                    die;
                }
            }

            $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
            $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

            if( $sendEmail == true ):
                echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message_success . '" }';
            else:
                echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
            endif;
        } else {
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!" }';
        }
    } else {
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Please <strong>Fill up</strong> all the Fields and Try Again." }';
    }
} else {
    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later." }';
}

?>
```

If I remove recaptcha from the form in the html page the mails get properly send, but with recaptcha I get an error message "Bot Detected..."
I have checked the API keys they are fine.

Then I used a different php snipet you can see the test page here: http://senoranabogados.com.ar/test2.html

This is the php code:

```
<?php

        $email;$comment;$captcha;
        if(isset($_POST['email'])){
          $email=$_POST['email'];
        }if(isset($_POST['comment'])){
          $email=$_POST['comment'];
        }if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
          $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
        }
        if(!$captcha){
          echo '<h2>Please check the the captcha form.</h2>';
          exit;
        }
    $secretKey = "your-recaptcha-secret-key";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secretKey."&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $responseKeys = json_decode($response,true);
        if(intval($responseKeys["success"]) !== 1) {
          echo '<h2>You are spammer ! Get the @$%K out</h2>';
        } else {
          echo '<h2>Thanks for posting comment.</h2>';
        }
?>
```

Here I get a a "Failed to enable crypto in..." error

No matter what I try I can't get recaptcha to work.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions I have temporarily solved the problem, the code doesn't work with php 5.6 y switched to 5.5 and now works fine. Don't know why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that my code is not compatible with PHP 5.6 so I changed it to 5.5 on my server and now it works fine. Hope this helps anyone in the future.