# file_get_contents() SSL error

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine, ssl, curl

I followed a certain tutorial found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/wordpress) to install Wordpress onto App Engine, using a SQL Cloud Database.

I'm up to the point when I have to run the setup script to download the Wordpress archive and plugins. When that command is ran I get the following errors:

```
Downloading the WordPress archive...

Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /Users/Me/Sites/Blog/src/Project.php on line 47

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /Users/Me/Sites/Blog/src/Project.php on line 47

Warning: file_get_contents(https://wordpress.org/latest.zip): failed to open stream: operation failed in /Users/Me/Sites/Blog/src/Project.php on line 47
```

I've looked at multiple resources to combat this issue such as, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more), where they suggest to set the verification to the peer to `false`, but I do not have that option within this project. I also found that someone suggested to use `curl` instead but I'm unsure how to use that without breaking the project.

Comment: What do you mean by "I do not have that option within this project" ? Is this a code you write or not?

Comment: Your error is line 47 of Project.php which is `file_put_contents($file, file_get_contents($url));` which you don't seem to have permission to do.

Comment: @Dekel I did not write this code. I'm using it within a project.

Comment: @TimHallman Yes, which is my problem. Using `file_put_contents` seems not to play nicely with certificates.