# unable to get the results from google oauth php by using

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-app-engine, google-oauth

i am using wamp server

Apache Version : [image]2.4.9
PHP Version : 5.5.12

i am using codeingter , it is working in love site a month ago i used this in localhost but now it is giving SSL certification error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. And more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more)

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented the google authentication (google/apiclient version 2.0) in my CodeIgniter project on my local xampp environment and got the same error. I solved this by downloading cacert.pem from here https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download

put it here `C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem`

then edit php.ini file and  put this line in this section

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; php.ini Options  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

curl.cainfo = "C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

Remember to restart your apache server after this. Really hope that this method will work on your wamp server too, if not please comment.

Comment: my Application runs in Appengine google PHP
i am using xampp nut still issue is there.