# SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, ssl, apache2, facebook-php-sdk

[file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. And more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more)
This answer is not working with me.I have already try it. I don't have "certificate verify failed" issue.

First all of I am new with server configuration.
My issue is when I am using local-machine in which OpenSSl and ssl certificate is not installed....then my code upload image successfully on Facebook Via using Facebook SDK for PHP.

But When I upload same code on Server where ssl enable and https working fine then my code showing me error :-

```
 Warning: fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol 


at ErrorHandler ->handleError ('2', 'fopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol', '/facebook/php-sdk-v4/src/Facebook/FileUpload/FacebookFile.php', '91', array())
```

I don't know what's going wrong. Is it any server configuration issue or anything else ?

My machine PHP version is:- PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.20 (cli)
My server PHP version is :- PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.4 (cli)

Comment: @Jay Blanchard this is not correct answer which one you mentioned I have already check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more OK

Comment: There are many others which are a duplicate to your question.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/63210/ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-openssl-error-messages-error140770fcssl-rou

Comment: @JayBlanchard this one related to SMTP and on my server SMTP is working perfect.

Comment: @JayBlanchard and also I don't have issue with "certificate verify failed" which one you mark duplicate question.

Comment: @Sid Did you ever get this resolved?