# SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, recaptcha

I am using http://www.question2answer.org/ software and standard plugin there for captcha. I tried to update software and after the upgrade I keep getting this error. I have no idea how to fix this. I looked around, but nothing is related directly.

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1.
>   OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in
>   /qa/qa-plugin/recaptcha-captcha/recaptchalib.php on line 128
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in
>   /qa/qa-plugin/recaptcha-captcha/recaptchalib.php on line 128
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(
>   https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=abc6LcMwv8SAAAAAN9QOkIlVKRQZzHS3DeZ8ZLxwxxcdsd-cs&response=03AOmkcwJV_JkhxK8hGJTIVKEDcPrNH5Y0wLwndp7v20Ipqd4HMO21LWHSyPsLFsdfdsfsdsdfsdA6FZ1LiFJZpl6-CmppsTAWc8Qzft_RXLvlzunzQtZWNDp0Kw8T-drMvHiOZf909v4ScysiPmaMrxkq_SSlJaOE_Q6sdfsdfdsfdsh5X7xLqvoFDFbV16BJBTkJ5Pot5ZDwmSGZSD_0pygTdEzh8j-tGuSpZLSDVJmQ7Xq6HR70Dd2idtKz_gfcIAZQisdfsdfdsfJHH1LyY3FAG_x9zHemy3tXF6oE7rWuBZ8JoHehkWhYYChe-cBbdSX1ZqPioNNaSvkREbooI7esdfsdfd3JkynEKlqnUBl3t__qpDMu&remoteip=12.102.238.217&version=php_1.1.2):
>   failed to open stream: operation failed in
>   /qa/qa-plugin/recaptcha-captcha/recaptchalib.php on line 128

I went to line 128 and this is what I see there. I see this line `"return file_get_contents(self::SITE_VERIFY_URL . $params->toQueryString());".` I have got more code around that lines for your info.

```
/**
 * Sends GET requests to the reCAPTCHA service.
 */
class ReCaptchaGetRequestMethod implements ReCaptchaRequestMethod{

    const SITE_VERIFY_URL = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?';

    /**
     * Submit the request with the specified parameters.
     *
     * @param ReCaptchaRequestParameters $params Request parameters
     * @return string Body of the reCAPTCHA response
     */
    public function submit(ReCaptchaRequestParameters $params){
        return file_get_contents(self::SITE_VERIFY_URL . $params->toQueryString());
    }
}
```

Can you please help ?  I tried few things like adding certificate in php.ini and it did not work. All of it was working fine, when I upgraded, it started to fail. All registrations are stuck. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the above is to use CURL based solution where you replace file_get_contents with CURL. Below is the new modified code. I have captured all in a [step by step blog article](https://www.whatareview.com/solution-openssl-error-messages-ssl-routinesssl3_get_server_certificate/) with steps for everyone.

```
$url = self::SITE_VERIFY_URL . $params->toQueryString();
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this corect solution, your error message says "SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed", it looks like it's the same as here https://stackoverflow.com/q/26148701/2360229

What you are doing now is: you set CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER = false

You also can do that with file_get_contents(), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/28701786/2360229

So, basically, you are just saying, that the function shall not verify the peer and this is how you surpress the initial error, but not solving the problem.