# The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error: 1416F086

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to install composer on Windows but I get the following error:

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:
>   1416F086: SSL routines: tls_process_server_certificate: certificate
>   verify failed Failed to enable crypto failed to open stream: operation
>   failed.

What's going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you try to go to that URL in the web browser on the server?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more) seems related. But I *don't* think it's a duplicate. The answers their recommend changing the `file_get_contents()` call, but OP should not be required to modify the composer installation script to get this done.

Comment: I have the same error on linode's [lamp stack docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/linode/lamp/).  It's pretty old though, using ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 4):

I have fixed it, the issue you have encountered seems to be related to a missing certificate.

You just need to add your certificate to end of this file:

> C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt

Here's an example how to append the certificate:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

> MIIDujCCAqKgAwIBAgILBAAAAAABD4Ym5g0wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQAwTDEgMB4GA1UECxMXR2xvYmFsU2>lnbiBSb290IENBIC0gUjIxEzARBgNVBAoTCkdsb2JhbFNpZ24xEzARBgNVBAMTCkdsb2Jh
>   bFNpZ24wHhcNMDYxMjE1MDgwMDAwWhcNMjE... (Your certificate)

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and this is how I solved the problem:
I followed the instructions in https://getcomposer.org/download/, paragraph below **Command-line installation**

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

I replaced line `php composer-setup.php` by `php composer-setup.php --disable-tls`

I got the idea from reviewing the code in composer-setup.php where I found the option. I should have ran `php composer-setup.php --help` to find the same answer faster and without reading code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in private network(Restricted Networking) such as Organization, you have to update their certificate in the "curl-ca-bundle.crt", Copy Paste your organization certificate code in the bottom of the "C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt" file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. You have to find below Certificate and install manually to Trusted root of "Current User/Local Computer".

```
C:\xampp\apache\bin\curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround I could run `composer` through its docker image:

```
docker run --rm --interactive --tty \
  --volume $PWD:/app \
  composer/composer install
```

I was bitten by this on my local Ubuntu machine. For no apparent reason, composer would time out.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced same issue and it was caused by VPN app that was running on my computer, exiting it fixed the issue.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33139786)

Answer (score 0):

I had to exit the VPN for it to work. Posting this for others who may need another alternative if nothing else seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error, after a hour work, because my linux server not have ssl, is on public ip.
I disable in code the request with https

Use this mode to download

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '55ce33d7678c5a611085589f1f3ddf8b3c52d662cd01d4ba75c0ee0459970c2200a51f492d557530c71c15d8dba01eae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php composer.phar install
```

I edit file composer-setup.php  ***/usr/src/a2billing/composer-setup.php***
line 755 remove https

```
$uriScheme = $this->disableTls ? 'http' : 'http';
```

and all done, the server can only request on http port 80

Answer (score 0):

I got around the situation by installing it as follows

```
apt install wget

sudo wget --no-check-certificate -O composer-setup.php https://getcomposer.org/installer

sudo php composer-setup.php --disable-tls --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Notice that I needed to disable the use of certificate

Answer (score -3):

I have fixed it, the issue you have encountered seems to be related to a missing certificate.
but if don't have certificate, try this... change composer directory else where but not to desktop and try install again.
it's real work to me!!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31991314)

Comment: not working in this way.