# How to read rss feed from html form

Tags: php, html, forms, rss, rss-reader

I am trying to build an HTML/PHP application where you type in an RSS URL into a form field and then retrieve the RSS feed in the browser as a result of going to the rssfeed.php page. Currently, I am getting an error `file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\week14\rssfeed.php on line 2`

Here is my index.html code:

```
<html>

<body>

<form action="rssfeed.php" method="post">
Please enter the RSS feed URL: <input type="content" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the rssfeed.php code:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents($_POST); 

?>
```

Not even sure what to google anymore, I am new to building code from scratch.

So this is what displays a feed from espn but I need to integrate this so that when I type the URL into the form it places that one into the place where the url in this code snippet currently is:

```
$feed_url = "http://rssfeeds.usatoday.com/UsatodaycomGolf-TopStories";
$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
   echo '<li>';
   echo '<a href="'.$entry->link.'" title="'.$entry->title.'" target="_blank">' . $entry->title . '</a>'; // output link & title
   echo $entry->description; // return post content
   echo '</li>';
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: `type="content"` < last I knew, there isn't an input of that type. http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/ - and is probably the root of the problem.

Comment: `file_get_contents($_POST);` - you will need to specify which field in `$_POST` to use as the filename.

Comment: the type should be URL since I am passing a URL thorough but then I want it to POST or embed itself so that it displays like when I go to the actual RSS Url but I can only do this with a live server so that could be half the problem because local host is not on the internet.

Comment: i need to tell the php file what file it is using?

Answer (score 1):

To give an idea how you can POST a url for some `RSSFeed` to a script and then process it perhaps this might help.

To process the contents of an RSSFeed typically one would use `DOMDocument` or `SimpleXML` - the code here simply loads the remote XML file directly into the `DOMDocument` and instantiates an XPath object to further query to find nodes. There are many other ways one could do this - but it was quickly written just as example.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RSS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <input type='text' name='name' value='https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/feeds/index.xml' />
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['name'] ) ){

                $dom=new DOMDocument;
                $dom->load( $_POST['name'] );

                $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
                $col=$xp->query( '//channel/item' );

                if( $col->length > 0 ){
                    foreach( $col as $node ){
                        printf( 
                            '<h3>%s</h3>', 
                            $xp->query('title',$node)->item(0)->textContent
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

a snippet from the output:

```
<h3>Where To Travel In 2020: The Top 10 Emerging Destinations</h3>
<h3>Gavin And Stacey Christmas Special: First Reviews Of Reunion Episode Are In</h3> 
<h3>Jeremy Corbyn Speaks To The Common People | The People's Election</h3>
```

A more complete example showing multiple possible RSS feeds and more fields from each article:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>RSS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <select name='name'>
                <optgroup label='World news'>
                    <option>http://rssfeeds.usatoday.com/UsatodaycomGolf-TopStories
                    <option>http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/worldNews
                    <option>http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition_world.rss
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label='UK news'>
                    <option>http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml
                    <option>http://feeds.skynews.com/feeds/rss/uk.xml
                    <option>http://feeds.reuters.com/reuters/UKdomesticNews
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label='US news'>
                    <option>http://rssfeeds.usatoday.com/usatoday-newstopstories
                    <option>http://feeds.reuters.com/Reuters/domesticNews
                    <option>http://feeds.skynews.com/feeds/rss/us.xml
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label='Miscellaneous'>
                    <option>https://www.wired.com/feed
                    <option>http://rss.slashdot.org/Slashdot/slashdot
                    <option>https://www.huffingtonpost.co.uk/feeds/index.xml
                </optgroup>
            </select>
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>
        <?php
            if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['name'] ) ){

                $url=$_POST['name'];
                $max=150;
                $ellipsis=str_repeat('.',5);




                $dom=new DOMDocument;
                $dom->load( $url );

                $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
                $col=$xp->query( '//channel/item' );

                if( $col->length > 0 ){


                    echo '<ul>';

                    foreach( $col as $node ){
                        try{
                            $description=$xp->evaluate('string(description)',$node);
                            if( strlen( $description ) > $max )$description=substr( $description, 0, $max ) . $ellipsis;

                            $category=$xp->evaluate( 'string(category)', $node );

                            printf( 
                                '<li>
                                    <a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>
                                    <div>Category: %s</div>
                                    <p>%s</p>
                                </li>',
                                $xp->evaluate( 'string(link)', $node ),
                                $xp->evaluate( 'string(title)',$node ),
                                $category,
                                $description
                            );
                        }catch( Exception $e ){
                            continue;
                        }
                    }

                    echo '</ul>';

                } else {
                    echo 'nothing found for given XPath query';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This helps as it gives me a place to begin, I figured XML would be needed but was not sure thank you. If I find how to do this through a form I will post it back into the question.

Comment: Erm, that is done `"through a form"` [  I simply hardcoded a value into the form field for purposes of this demo ] - the form posts the URL to, on this occasion, the same page but could be your `rssfeed.php` script. Presumably your `rssfeed.php` script would process and display? If yes, you cld utilise the PHP code from above as basis for the `rssfeed.php` script...

Comment: so I did separate them in the site, but this one only displays the headings for the titles of the articles, what would you use to display the whole feed in html? I am looking on W3 schools and playing with it but nothing so far. it is located at http://eleanor.codes/week14

Answer (score 0):

Granted this only reads http links not https:

Index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" type="text/css">
        <title>RSS Feed Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>RSS Search</h2>
        <form form action="rss.php" method="post">
            <input type='text' name='name' value='' />
            <input type='submit'>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

rss.php:

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['name'] ) ){
$feed_url = ( $_POST['name'] );
$content = file_get_contents($feed_url);
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($x->channel->item as $entry) {
   echo '<li>';
   echo '<a href="'.$entry->link.'" title="'.$entry->title.'" target="_blank">' . $entry->title . '</a>'; // output link & title
   echo $entry->description; // return post content
   echo '</li>';
}
echo "</ul>";
};
        ?>
```

Comment: to use `file_get_contents` with SSL enable links ( not all ) you need to use the `context` argument to that function and configure it for ssl ~ this might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto