# How do i resolve this error in PHP: file_get_contents(): SSL: Success

Tags: php

My website is https://www.mystylequest.com. We provide answers to fashion related questions like "can I find this dress in Yellow?". Answering a question involves submitting a link to a website with the dress, then my website scraps the neccessary images from the submitted link. However, we keep getting this error: `file_get_contents(): SSL: Success` upon submitting a valid image link (eg: https://poshmark.com/listing/Blue-and-White-Striped-Palazzo-Pants-5cf5ccaf6a7fbadddcaf2f07).

Here is the code:

```
if (isset($_POST['SubmitAnswersWithImage'])) {
    $image_url = trim($_POST['AnswerImg']);
    $url = trim($_POST['AnswerUrl']);
    $postId = (int)$_POST['PostId'];

    // This is to bypass websites that block our ip
    $aContext = array(
        'http' => array(
            'proxy' => 'tcp://138.68.161.60:8080',
            'request_fulluri' => true,
         ),
    );
    $cxContext = stream_context_create($aContext);
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url, false, $cxContext); // Error occurs
    $web_url = GoogleStorageManager::uploadBlob('quest_answers', $image_data)->webUrl();
<!-- irrelevant code -->
```

Any solutions will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: This answer solve you problem? [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto)

Comment: Will check it out @SimoneRossaini

Answer (score 0):

try

```
// This is to bypass websites that block our ip
$aContext = array(
    'http' => array(
        'proxy' => 'tcp://138.68.161.60:8080',
        'request_fulluri' => true,
     ),
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ),
);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php

An official document describing the changes made to open ssl in PHP 5.6 From here I learned of one more parameter I should have set to false: "verify_peer_name"=>false

> **Note:** This has very significant security implications. Disabling
>   verification potentially permits a MITM attacker to use an invalid
>   certificate to eavesdrop on the requests. While it may be useful to do
>   this in local development, other approaches should be used in
>   production.

Comment: Will try this, but can you give an explanation?

Comment: Thanks for your effort @MikeFoxtech, but still we are not getting the required results. Images are still not downloading