# stream_socket_enable_crypto():SSL operation failed with code error on Cent OS 7 and there is no CA set

Tags: php, openssl, centos

I recently embarked on a PHP project on CentOS 7 and configured the email to work with Office365. The mails worked fine for a while until I started observing this error whenever a mail attempts to be sent:

> stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL error messages:error1416F086: SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Furthermore, the `openssl.ca` file and `openssl.ca` path directives in the openssl section of `phpinfo()` are set to `null`.

Could someone please suggest how I could fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file\_get\_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1, Failed to enable crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto)