# Simple HTML DOM Parser error: "Warning: file_get_contents()"

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I was just starting to test use Simple HTML DOM Parser to parse google.com, while getting the following error:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed in /Applications/Ampps/www/scraper/simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php on line 82
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /Applications/Ampps/www/scraper/simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php on line 82
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(https://google.com): failed to open stream: operation failed in /Applications/Ampps/www/scraper/simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php on line 82

And my scraper_test.php looks like this:

```
include('./simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('https://google.com');
echo $html->find('title', 0)->plaintext;
```

Comment: This question might be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file\_get\_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1, Failed to enable crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto)