# file_get_contents certificate verify failed

Tags: php, nginx, ssl, openssl, lets-encrypt

I have a server hosted on nginx through letsencrypt. I had no issues running file_get_contents up until several days ago when it keeps running into the error. However, there has no been changes in the settings of the server within these few days.

[image]

What could be the cause of this error?

And how can i go about resolving this?

Attempted solutions

1. Setting a path for php init

***(Didnt work, same error)***

```
curl.cainfo = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"

openssl.cafile = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt"
```

***(Didnt work, same error)***

```
curl.cainfo = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/fullchain.pem"

openssl.cafile = "/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain_name/fullchain.pem"
```

***(Didnt work, same error)***

2. Renewing lets encrypt certificate

***Information derived from phpinfo()***
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are you actually doing with `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: making a POST request to a 3rd party API.

I didnt use to have any issues with this set of code though

Comment: This is just a guess, but could it be that the certificate, used by this 3rd party API, has expired?

Comment: I think the error definitely has something to do with my server.

If i were to run the code locally, i have no issues making the post request

Comment: @KIKOSoftware do you have any idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: No, I have no idea. Did you actually try to access the 3rd party API from elsewhere, and did it worked from there? I cannot make sense of what you say about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238265/discussion-between-yeo-bryan-and-kiko-software).

Comment: Please check your server against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for anything problematic, specifically chain issues.

Comment: What if you [ignore TLS check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151993/6934036)

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, resolved by removing RootCA certificate, last in fullchain.pem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).