# why is my Wordpress site giving error codes in the footer?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a website built with Wordpress that has many errors showing in the footer. How can I remove them?

see some of the error codes here:

```
Warning: getimagesize(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed in /home/lappie1/domains/laptopshuren.nl/public_html/wp-content/themes/laptopshuren /sb_libs/sb_utilities.php on line 408

Warning: getimagesize(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/lappie1/domains/laptopshuren.nl/public_html/wp-content/themes/laptopshuren/sb_libs/sb_utilities.php on line 408

Warning: getimagesize(https://laptopshuren.nl/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Rode-kruis.jpg): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/lappie1/domains/laptopshuren.nl/public_html/ wp-content/themes/laptopsuren/sb_libs/sb_utilities.php on line 408

Warning: Unsupported file type! in /home/lappie1/domains/laptopshuren.nl/public_html/wp-content/themes/laptopshuren/sb_libs/sb_utilities.php on line 413

Warning: Division by zero in /home/lappie1/domains/laptopshuren.nl/public_html/wp-content/themes/laptopshuren/sb_libs/sb_utilities.php on line 436
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get the codes out of the site?

Comment: Read this - https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39807251/1427878