# How to start pulling data via rest api - php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, api

I'm trying to integrate with the [REST Countries V2 API](https://restcountries.com/#api-endpoints-v2) to pull country data and display it on a webpage I'm making. I was pointed in the direction of curl so I have updated the question to what I am trying.

So far I have this code:

```html
<?

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all',
                 CURLOPT_HEADER => false
                );

curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

Its pulling an enormous JSON list onto my page. I'm not super familiar with JSON, how can I target the specific pieces of data such as the country name. Is it possible to do with with php as I'm more familiar with php than javascript and I would like to make a nice grid layout using a php foreach loop with each country having its own card.

Comment: what PHP version are you using?

Comment: try  using ```curl```

Comment: What your doing will work, though only b/c what you're doing is extremely basic (you'll need to look into curl for more advanced requests). The issue is that whatever server/computer you're running this on does not have the correct ssl certificate(s) to validate that url.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [file\_get\_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1, Failed to enable crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-failed-to-enable-crypto)

Comment: @GrafiCode I'm using PHP version: 7.3.5

Comment: @steveyout I've read a bit about curl, do I have to install it on my system or is it a php function?

Comment: its is an inbuilt php function

Comment: @steveyout thank you! I will start my searches in that direction! I'd upvote your comments but I'm too new :(

Comment: it works, except the part when you try to access `data`: https://i.ibb.co/X4vBWZV/Schermata-a-2022-10-04-19-31-31.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try curl

```
$ch = curl_init("https://restcountries.com/v2/all");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$response=json_decode($response);
foreach ($response as $country){
    echo $country->name;
    echo $country->flag;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I've just found a bit of code that is giving me some output using curl and I've updated the question above!

Comment: for each country??

Comment: That was the game plan, I'm picturing using a foreach loop and hopefully will be able to store the values I want like the country name and country flag in a php variable?

Comment: Thank you so much my dog! I'd upvote you as well but I'm still too new, once I get 15 rep I'll come back and show you the love :)