# webrivers - How to integrate sms main server using php?

Tags: php, mysql

This code works fine on xampp localhost fine but does not work on the server host.

Any idea what might be wrong?

```
$contact_no = $_POST['contact_no'];
$message = $_POST['text_message'];
$message = urlencode($message);

$url = 'http://trsms.krispal.in/API/pushsms.aspx?username=xxxx&password=xxxx&senderid=MYDMAL&mobile='.$contact_no.'&text='.$message;
$xml = file_get_contents($url);
echo $xml;
echo "<script>alert('Message has been successfully send...')</script>";
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No error issue..

Comment: Check if your HOST disable file_get_contents function, Usually they disable it on shared host for security reasons.

Comment: @B.Mossavari It's fine as an answer. It's not automatically a comment just because it's short. I think it's most likely the correct answer, in fact.

Comment: Ok, I'll undelete my answer then...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729829/file-get-contents-not-working-on-production-server-fine-on-local

Comment: Maybe try another website instead of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if your HOST disable file_get_contents function ,
Usually they disable it on shared host for security reasons.
check server php configuration (php.ini)  something like

```
allow_url_fopen=0
```

could broke file_get_contents functionality